# Factorization of a polynomial of degree 2

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I want to find a factorization of the following polynomial of degree 2.

Let $\alpha >0, \beta > 0,$ and $\gamma \geq 1$. Is there any hope to factorize the following polynomial:
$$
\alpha^2 x^2 + \beta^2 y^2 - 2 \alpha \beta \gamma xy = C(Ax- By)^2,
$$
for some positive constants $A, B, C$.

Thank you in advance

S

Comment: I just edited your post. The word is 'polynomial' in English (in fact, you spelt it correctly in your first line!).

Comment: Well done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Old answer**

Your expression can be factorized of we set $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha\beta}}$. In that case, $C=1, A=\sqrt{\alpha}$, and $B=\sqrt{\beta}$.

Edit: as done by JY1853, comparing coefficients is the way.

Comment: Sorry I edit the polynom to $\alpha^2 x^2 + \beta^2 y^2 - 2 \alpha \beta \gamma xy$.  When I did some identification using development I get the following:

$$ A = \frac{\alpha \gamma}{\beta}, B = \gamma, C = \frac{\beta^2}{\gamma^2}$$
However developing $C(Ax- By)^2 = \alpha^2 x^2 + \beta^2 y^2 - 2\alpha\beta xy$ (there is no $\gamma$ term in front of the monom $xy$. :(

Answer (score 0):

If we expand the RHS first:

$C(Ax-By)^2=C(A^2x^2+B^2y^2-2ABxy)=CA^2x^2+CB^2y^2-2ABCxy$

Comparing coefficients with the LHS now:

$CA^2=\alpha^2$ (1)

$CB^2=\beta^2$ (2)

$-2ABC=-2\alpha\beta\gamma\implies ABC=\alpha\beta\gamma$

Multiplying together (1) and (2), we have $C^2A^2B^2=\alpha^2\beta^2$, which means that your polynomial can only be factored into the form $C(Ax-By)^2$ if $\gamma=1$.

Comment: Even more, I think it an "iff" $\gamma = 1$. Thank you for your suggestions.
Actually I try to lower bound this polynomial. 
 Please could you check this 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436633/lower-bound-of-a-polynomial-of-degree-2/3436638#3436638